# How to plot mirror plots? (Two plots sharing the same x-axis, but one is upside down - below the axis)

Tags: r, plot

Suppose I have two samples that I would like to compare graphically. One way to do it is to lay one over another like below:

```
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = rnorm(100, mean=2)
plot(density(x1))
lines(density(x2), col="red")
```

I wonder however if there is a way to plot x2 such that the plot shares the same axis as the plot of x1, except that it is upside down, like the plot below. It would be especially great if there is any method that does not involve downloading additional packages.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't matter if the y-axis contains values below zero, you can use this:

```
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100, mean=2)
dens1 <- density(x1)
dens2 <- density(x2)
dens2$y <- dens2$y * -1
plot(dens1, 
     ylim = range(c(dens1$y, dens2$y)),
     xlim = range(c(dens1$x, dens2$x)),
     main = "",
     xlab = "")
lines(dens2, col = "red")
```

[image: densitys]

Comment: That's the way I'd have gone -- tho' you could save a couple steps by `ylim = range(c(dens1$y,-dens2$y))`  and `lines(dens2$x,-dens2$y)` ... or even  `x2 <- -rnorm(100, m=2)`

Comment: Right, `lines(dens2$x,-dens2$y)` would be simpler, but `x2 <- -rnorm(100, m=2)` would not work since the density is always positive, independent of the values of the variable.

Comment: Yep, sorry about not paying attention to `density`

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse the axis of a plot by using the argument `ylim=(...)` (or `xlim=(...)`) and specifying the limits in the reverse order.

For example:

```
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol=1))
par(mai=c(0.5, 1, 0.5, 1))

plot(c(-6, 6), 0:1, type="n", ylim=c(0, 1), xlab="", ylab="")
lines(density(x1), ylim=c(0, 1))

plot(c(-6, 6), 0:1, type="n", ylim=c(1, 0), xlab="", ylab="")
lines(density(x2), col="red", ylim=c(1, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know a way to combine the two plots such that they share one axis? I like the simplicity of changing the direction of the ylim. Never would've thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get only one x-axis using the `mar` argument of the `par` function. The R code would look like this:

```
   #Create Data
    x1 = rnorm(100)
    x2 = rnorm(100, mean=2)

    #Make the plot
    par(mfrow=c(2,1))
    par(mar=c(0,5,3,3))
    plot(density(x1) , main="" , xlab="", ylim=c(0,1) , xaxt="n", las=1 , col="slateblue1" , lwd=4 )
    par(mar=c(5,5,0,3))
    plot(density(x2) , main="" , xlab="Value of my variable", ylim=c(1,0) , las=1 , col="tomato3" , lwd=4)
```

Giving this plot:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keOCY.png)

This graph is present in the [R graph gallery](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com)